# Print exception message in Laravel abort page

Tags: php, laravel, exception, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2. I am aborting the user for 403 page with the `abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');` command. This will redirects to 403 page. And prints the `Unauthorized action` message. But if I use custom blade for 403 page means how to print `Unauthorized action` message which given inside the `abort` function. I have searched through internet, and Laravel error pages document also. But I can't find the solution. How to print `Unauthorized action` message in my custom template file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your view you can get your message by call `{{ $exception->getMessage() }}`

When you call abort function it creates new Exception(`HttpException`), and first parameter passes like code and second like message.